# Which Docker Orchestration Tools Can Manage Multiple Environments?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-swarm, orchestration

I'm still a bit of a Docker/container n00b, so please bear with me. I'd like to maintain 3 categories of environments for an application that consists of a:

1. Web API (e.g. ASP.NET, Node.js, etc.)
2. Database (e.g. Postgres, MySQL, etc.)
3. Application Cache (e.g. Redis, Memcached, etc.)

The 3 categories needed are:

1. Production
2. Staging
3. Internal, which could be used by various dev teams with their own branch of the code and data

[image: my idea]

Do the orchestration solutions like Swarm and Kubernetes handle this scenario such that the containers within a category know about the others (e.g. Web3 knows about DB3 and Cache3 but none of the others), and would they be able to easily accommodate adding another trio of containers (Web+DB+Cache) to one of the existing categories (e.g. Internal)?

Answer (score 1):

In Kubernetes this is possible through the use of `Namespaces`.

I don't want to get to in-depth if you are like you say a "Kubernetes n00b", but Docker containers are held in `Pods` and talk to each through `Services`, both of which can be restricted to a specific `Namespace`.

So you could have a `Pod` called "front-end" that talks to a `Pod` called "backend-end" through the "back-end" `Service`, this could be deployed three time in three different `Namespaces` and each "front-end" `Pod` would live in it's `Namespace` and talk to it's own "back-end" `Pod` through it's own "back-end" `Service` all in the same `Namespace`.